# Cordova doesn't download JSON in the Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a problem with Cordova and Android. I have a web application and I need to download data which I was generated in the application. I have a button which calls a function which creates a new element with href to the JSON. When I clicked the button in the browser on the PC or Android (Chrome), it works fine. Shows me dialog if I want to download the file. However when I generated app via Cordova, the download button doesn't work. When I clicked on the button, nothing happens. I have installed Cordova whitelist plugin and allow href in the config.xml and in the Content-Security-Policy element I have default-src data:

This is example:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="downloadButton">Download</button>
    <div id="download"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

A part of javascript:

```
    app.initialize();

    document.getElementById("downloadButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
       download();
    });
    function download() {
        var json = {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}; //in the application is objest with data
        var data = 'data:text/json;charser=utf8,'+ encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json));
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = data;
        a.download = 'data.json';
        document.getElementById("download").appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    }
```

A part of config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
```